# jQuery Tooltip not working with detach(), appendTo, etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this jQuery Tools [ToolTip widget](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

It works great in a situation like this:

```
    ...
<a id="A1">trigger</a> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#trigger").tooltip({ effect: 'slide' });
    });
</script>
    ...
```

But this will not work and it's what i want to do:

```
$("<a id='trigger'>trigger</a>").appendTo("body");
//console.log(myTrigger);

$("#trigger").tooltip({ effect: 'slide' });
$("#trigger").tooltip().show();
```

**Can i dynamically add the trigger element so i can place the tooltip wherever i want? If so, how?**

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Theres a scripting api associated with the flowplayer plugins.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/scripting.html

This is the same for all of their plugins but the parameters will be different. Look 3/4's the way down the [tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) page for the parameters.

Comment: Do you have example code or pseudo-code? not sure where you mean by 3/4's the way down.

Comment: scroll 3/4's the way down the page to the title that says `Scripting API`

Comment: yeah, i don't see anything in there that can help me. I'm trying to use .append() or .appendTo() to dynamically add the tooltip. I get the tooltip to work fine, just not with append() or appendTo().

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if i append it somewhere other than body such as a wrapper div:

```
$("<a id='trigger'>trigger</a>").appendTo($("#wrapper"));

$("#trigger").tooltip({ effect: 'slide' });
$("#trigger").tooltip().show();
```